# Access with mutex has more speed on more cpu

Tags: go

I tried some synchronization techniques to share state between goroutines and find out that incorrect variant (without sync) works slowly than same program with mutex.

Given the code:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mu sync.Mutex
    hash := make(map[string]string)
    hash["test"] = "string"
    num := 40000000
    wg.Add(num)
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        go func() {
            mu.Lock()
            _, _ = hash["test"]
            mu.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

Perform on my laptop with 8 HT cores for 9-10 seconds.
But if just remove sync it works for 11-12 seconds:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    hash := make(map[string]string)
    hash["test"] = "string"
    num := 40000000
    wg.Add(num)
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        go func() {
            _, _ = hash["test"]
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

A synced version is faster and unitizes CPU much higher. Question is why?

My thought is about how goroutines scheduled and overhead for context switching because of the more GOMAXPROCS the greater the gap between these two versions. But I can't explain the real reason for that that happens under the hood of the scheduler.

Comment: When you have a data race the results are undefined. You are comparing a defined result to an undefined result. Therefore, your conclusions are invalid.

Comment: @peterSO I didn't compare the results of computing, I just want to know what happens under the hood of go's runtime. Why undefined results take more time than defined.

Comment: You have undefined results because the process is undefined. Therefore, there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: @peterSO ok, just to stop debate about undefined results, I deleted data race code and the result remained exactly the same as with data race.

Comment: @abonec Peter is correct, however to continue, the version with the mutex is faster because lock contention has been reduced, see the implementation comments of maps https://golang.org/src/sync/map.go?s=1149:2596#L17